# How do I accomplish this with url rewriting?

Tags: html, .htaccess, web

I have a menu, which when you open goes to /#0 to indicate that the menu has been opened and the menu the slides in and shows. What I want to know is how to rewrite the url so that instead of site.com/#0 we simply get site.com. I believe this can be done with .htaccess though I'm not quite sure how. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the code thats involves the actions you mentioned

Comment: @angad dubey yeah sorry it's literally just this: <header class="cd-header">
      <img src="img/ss-logo.png" style='width: 200px, height: auto;'></p>
      <a href="#0" class="cd-3d-nav-trigger">
      Menu
      <span></span>
      </a>
    </header>

Comment: Do you instead mean that you don't want the menu to save its state in the URL? Then show the menu code and explain what you have tried. Rewrites aren't going to help here.

Comment: @Matt.Christopher Can you show us the JS you use to open the menu ?

Comment: You can find my entire js file here http://hastebin.com/eyovixupin.coffee

Comment: @Matt.Christopher Please post the code here.

Comment: The entire file is too long to post but the important part is here:jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 //toggle 3d navigation
 $('.cd-3d-nav-trigger').on('click', function(){
  toggle3dBlock(!$('.cd-header').hasClass('nav-is-visible'));
 });

Comment: @angad dubey this may also be useful: $.fn.removeClassPrefix = function(prefix) {
     this.each(function(i, el) {
         var classes = el.className.split(" ").filter(function(c) {
             return c.lastIndexOf(prefix, 0) !== 0;
         });
         el.className = $.trim(classes.join(" "));
     });
     return this;
 };

Answer (score -1):

Please try this if I'm getting your point.

```
    # Rewrite --- www.site.com/#0 => www.site.com

    RewriteRule ^$ /?&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,  I seem to get an error 500 with that when trying to access the homepage [internal server error]

Comment: have you define any site url first before this rule?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean, how do I do that?